# How can I include Images in the Backstage Ribbon of my Outlook AddIn (VSTO, C#, XML)?

Tags: c#, xml, outlook, vsto

In the Backstage Ribbon of my Outlook AddIn the user can switch on and off the individual functions of the AddIn by means of check boxes. I would like to add images to the left of the functionality to make it a bit more visual. So far I can only do this with buttons (see picture). Is there a possibility to replace the buttons with pure images? The buttons have no function anyway. Attached is my XML code for the ribbon so far.[image]

```
<backstage>
    <tab id="tabAddInSettings" label="Versendeeinstellungen" title="Versendeeinstellungen" insertAfterMso="ApplicationOptionsDialog" enabled="true" visible="true" columnWidthPercent="50">
        <firstColumn>
            <group id="groupIntroduction" label="Das Add-In hilft unbeabsichtigte Fehler beim Versenden von E-Mails zu vermeiden.">
                <topItems>
                    <labelControl id="labelEmptyLine1" label="    " enabled="true" visible="true"/>
                    <labelControl id="Introduction" label="Hierzu müssen die gewünschten Funktionen in der Menüleiste durch Anklicken aktiviert werden (blau hinterlegt, wenn aktiv)." enabled="true" visible="true"/>
                    <labelControl id="labelEmptyLine2" label="    " enabled="true" visible="true"/>
                </topItems>
            </group>
            <group id="groupBlacklist" label="Wörter, die auf einen Anhang hinweisen">
                <primaryItem>
                    <button id="buttonBlackList" label="Wörter, die auf einen Anhang hinweisen" imageMso="AdpStoredProcedureQueryUpdate" onAction="OnAnhangBlackList" enabled="true" visible="true"/>
                </primaryItem>
                <topItems>
                    <labelControl id="labelBlacklistExplain1" enabled="true" visible="true" label="Wenn eine E-Mail mindestens ein Wort aus dieser Liste enthält, aber kein Anhang vorhanden ist, erscheint vor dem Versenden eine Warnung."/>
                    <labelControl id="labelBlacklistExplain2" enabled="true" visible="true" label="Diese Liste kann hier angepasst werden."/>
                </topItems>
            </group>
            <group id="groupInternalDomains" label="Interne Domains">
                <primaryItem>
                    <button id="buttonInternalDomains" label="Interne Domains" imageMso="CheckNames" onAction="OnInternalDomains" enabled="true" visible="true"/>
                </primaryItem>
                <topItems>
                    <labelControl id="labelDomainsExplain1" enabled="true" visible="true" label="Befinden sich Empfänger einer E-Mail außerhalb der eigenen Organisation, erscheint vor dem Versenden eine Warnung."/>
                    <labelControl id="labelDomainsExplain2" enabled="true" visible="true" label="Die Liste mit internen Domains kann hier angepasst werden."/>
                </topItems>
            </group>
            <group id="groupVertraulichkeitsvermerk" label="Vertraulichkeitsvermerk">
                <primaryItem>
                    <button id="buttonVertraulichkeitsvermerk" label="Vertraulichkeitsvermerk" imageMso="SourceControlRun" onAction="OnVertraulichkeitsvermerk" enabled="true" visible="true"/>
                </primaryItem>
                <topItems>
                    <labelControl id="labelCriticalNumberExplain1" enabled="true" visible="true" label="Befindet sich ein Anhang in einer E-Mail erscheint eine Abfrage, die es ermöglicht einen Vertraulichkeitsvermerk hinzuzufügen."/>
                    <labelControl id="labelCriticalNumberExplain2" enabled="true" visible="true" label="Dieser kann hier angepasst werden."/>
                </topItems>
            </group>
            <group id="groupEmptyLines">
                <topItems>
                    <labelControl id="labelEmptyLine3" getVisible="EL3" label="     "/>
                    <labelControl id="labelEmptyLine4" getVisible="EL4" label="     "/>
                    <labelControl id="labelEmptyLine5" getVisible="EL5" label="     "/>
                    <labelControl id="labelEmptyLine6" getVisible="EL6" label="     "/>
                    <labelControl id="labelEmptyLine7" getVisible="EL7" label="     "/>
                    <labelControl id="labelEmptyLine8" getVisible="EL8" label="     "/>
                    <labelControl id="labelEmptyLine9" getVisible="EL9" label="     "/>
                    <labelControl id="labelEmptyLine10" getVisible="EL10" label="     "/>
                    <labelControl id="labelEmptyLine11" getVisible="EL11" label="     "/>
                    <labelControl id="labelEmptyLine12" getVisible="EL12" label="     "/>
                    <labelControl id="labelEmptyLine13" getVisible="EL13" label="     "/>
                    <labelControl id="labelEmptyLine14" getVisible="EL14" label="     "/>
                    <labelControl id="labelEmptyLine15" getVisible="EL15" label="     "/>
                    <labelControl id="labelEmptyLine16" getVisible="EL16" label="     "/>
                    <labelControl id="labelEmptyLine17" getVisible="EL17" label="     "/>
                    <labelControl id="labelEmptyLine18" getVisible="EL18" label="     "/>
                    <labelControl id="labelEmptyLine19" getVisible="EL19" label="     "/>
                    <labelControl id="labelEmptyLine20" getVisible="EL20" label="     "/>
                    <labelControl id="labelEmptyLine21" getVisible="EL21" label="     "/>
                    <labelControl id="labelEmptyLine22" getVisible="EL22" label="     "/>
                    <labelControl id="labelEmptyLine23" getVisible="EL23" label="     "/>
                    <labelControl id="labelEmptyLine24" getVisible="EL24" label="     "/>
                </topItems>
            </group>
            <group id="groupCopyright">
                <bottomItems>
                    <hyperlink enabled="true" visible="true" id="HyperLink" getTarget="OnCopyright" label="Copyright (2022)"/>
                    <labelControl id="labelCopyright1" enabled="true" visible="true" label="Dieses Add-In entstand im Rahmen eines Projekts im Studiengang Wirtschaftsinformatik der Dualen Hochschule Baden-Württemberg Stuttgart."/>
                    <labelControl id="labelCopyright2" enabled="true" visible="true" label="Mitwirkende: N. Kirschner, S. Boese, C. Franz"/>
                    <labelControl id="labelCopyright3" enabled="true" visible="true" label="Betreuung durch: I. Marevic, M. Schlegel, Prof. Dr. T. Straub"/>
                </bottomItems>
            </group>
        </firstColumn>

        <secondColumn>
            <group id="groupExplain" label="Im Folgenden werden alle Funktionen des AddIns beschrieben.">
                <topItems>
                    <labelControl id="labelEmptyLine25" label="    " enabled="true" visible="true"/>
                    <labelControl id="Explain" label="Diese können weiter unten durch Anklicken der Checkboxen aktiviert und deaktiviert werden." enabled="true" visible="true"/>
                    <labelControl id="labelEmptyLine26" label="    " enabled="true" visible="true"/>
                </topItems>
            </group>
            
            <group id="AttachmentCheckExplain" label="Anhangwarnung">
                <primaryItem>
                    <button id="buttonAttachmentCheck" imageMso="AttachMenu" enabled="false" visible="true"/>
                </primaryItem>
                <topItems>
                    <labelControl id="labelAttachmentCheckExplain" enabled="true" visible="true" label="Ist diese Funktion aktiviert, wird der Sendevorgang einer Mail abgebrochen, sobald sie ein Wort aus der Anhangliste links enthält und gleichzeitig KEIN Anhang hinzugefügt wurde."/>
                    <checkBox id="boxAttachmentCheck" onAction="OnAttachmentCheck" screentip="Warnung bei vergessenem Anhang" supertip="Warnen, wenn Sie diese E-Mail senden möchten, in der ggf. ein Anhang fehlt." label="Anhang Warnung" enabled="true" visible="true" />
                </topItems>
            </group>

            <group id="ConfidentialCheckExplain" label="Vertraulichkeitsvermerk">
                <primaryItem>
                    <button id="buttonConfidentialCheck"  imageMso="SourceControlRun" enabled="false" visible="true"/>
                </primaryItem>
                <topItems>
                    <labelControl id="labelConfidentialCheckExplain" enabled="true" visible="true" label="Ist diese Funktion aktiviert, erscheint vor dem Senden einer Mail, die einen Anhang enthält, eine Meldung, die es dem Nutzer ermöglicht, der Mail einen Vertraulichkeitsvermerk hinzuzufügen. Dieser kann links angepasst werden."/>
                    <checkBox id="boxConfidentialCheck" onAction="OnConfidentialCheck"  enabled="true" visible="true" screentip="Vertraulichkeitsvermerk hinzufügen" supertip="Hinweis, ob ein Vertraulichkeitsvermerk eingefügt werden soll, wenn ein Anhang eingefügt wurde." label="Vertraulichkeitsvermerk"/>
                </topItems>
            </group>

            <group id="ExternalCheckExplain" label="Empfängerabgleich">
                <primaryItem>
                    <button id="buttonExternalCheck"  imageMso="CheckNames" enabled="false" visible="true"/>
                </primaryItem>
                <topItems>
                    <labelControl id="labelExternalCheckExplain" enabled="true" visible="true" label="Ist diese Funktion aktiviert, wird vor dem Senden einer Mail geprüft, ob die Anrede der E-Mail dem Namen des Empfängers entspricht."/>
                    <checkBox id="boxExternalCheck" onAction="OnExternalCheck" enabled="true" visible="true" screentip="Warnung bei Empfänger-Domains außerhalb der eigenen Organisation" supertip="Warnen, dass sich Empfänger dieser E-Mail außerhalb der eigenen Organisation befinden." label="Extern Warnung"/>
                </topItems>
            </group>

            <group id="RecipientCheckExplain" label="Externwarnung">
                <primaryItem>
                    <button id="buttonRecipientCheck"  imageMso="AccessTableContacts" enabled="false" visible="true"/>
                </primaryItem>
                <topItems>
                    <labelControl id="labelRecipientCheckExplain" enabled="true" visible="true" label="Ist diese Funktion aktiviert, wird vor dem Senden einer Mail geprüft, ob sich der Empfänger innerhalb der eigenen Organisation befindet. In diesem Fall wird eine Warnung angezeigt. Die Liste interner Domains kann links angepasst werden."/>
                    <checkBox id="boxRecipientCheck" onAction="OnRecipientCheck" enabled="true" visible="true" screentip="Warnung bei falscher Anrede" supertip="Warnen, wenn die Anrede der E-Mail nicht dem Namen des Empfängers entspricht." label="Anredeabgleich"/>
                </topItems>
            </group>

            <group id="NameCheckExplain" label="Adressbuchdopplung">
                <primaryItem>
                    <button id="buttonNameCheck"  imageMso="CreateFormWithMultipleItems" enabled="false" visible="true"/>
                </primaryItem>
                <topItems>
                    <labelControl id="labelNameCheckExplain" enabled="true" visible="true" label="Ist diese Funktion aktiviert, wird geprüft, ob im Adressbuch mehrere Empfänger mit dem gleichen Namen enthalten sind. Ist dies der Fall erscheint eine Abfrage, ob der richtige Empfänger gewählt wurde. "/>
                    <checkBox id="boxNameCheck" onAction="OnNameCheck" enabled="true" visible="true" screentip="Warnung bei gleichnamigen Adressbuch-Einträgen" supertip="Warnen, wenn mehrere Einträge im Adressbuch denselben Vor- und/oder Zunamen haben." label="Warnung bei Adressbuchdopplung"/>
                </topItems>
            </group>

            <group id="TimeDelayedCheckExplain" label="zeitverzögertes Senden">
                <primaryItem>
                    <button id="buttonTimeDelayedCheck"  imageMso="Undo" enabled="false" visible="true"/>
                </primaryItem>
                <topItems>
                    <labelControl id="labelTimeDelayedCheckExplain" enabled="true" visible="true" label="Ist diese Funktion aktiviert, verbleibt die Mail nach dem Senden für weitere 2min im Postausgang, um so eine Rückruffunktion für fälschlich versendete Mails zu ermöglichen."/>
                    <checkBox id="boxTimeDelayedCheck" onAction="OnTimeDelayed" enabled="true" visible="true" screentip="E-Mails zeitverzögert versenden" supertip="Diese E-Mail verlässt zwei Minuten später den Postausgang. In dieser Zeit kann die E-Mail verschoben/gelöscht werden." label="Zeitverzögertes Senden"/>
                </topItems>
            </group>

                            
        </secondColumn>
    </tab>
</backstage>
```

Comment: See : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/57d152ea-7593-4848-9305-0d61250f7e3b/c-buttonhow-to-add-image-or-icon?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 1):

You can have your own images on the buttons. Not sure if it is possible to get rid of the buttons at all on the backstage and replace them with images (there is no such control in ribbon AFAIK), but your own images on the buttons are definitely possible. To achieve this, you can declare a callback to get image in your ribbon markup, and then define that callback to return your image in your addin's code. Assuming you have your image in your addin's resources as "YOUR_IMAGE", instead of `imageMso` you could use `getImage` callback:

```
// in your ribbon file:
<button id="buttonBlackList" ... getImage="GetRibbonImageCallback" />
```

```
/// in your ribbon handler:
public Bitmap GetRibbonImageCallback(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
 return (Bitmap)Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("YOUR_IMAGE");
}
```